# What URL's does Microsoft SmartScreen Filter need to access so it can work?

Tags: proxy

I need to add the URL's that IE is accessing for SmartScreen Filter to our proxy server white list.  Since we've enabled our white list we get a popup from IE that it can't access the SmartScreen filters.

I've googled various variations on that question but I keep coming back to how you can manage what URL's it filters.

I've found the windows update URL's (shown below), but it seems that the SmartScreen ones are different.

- .download.windowsupdate.com
- .update.microsoft.com
- .windowsupdate.com
- .windowsupdate.microsoft.com
- download.microsoft.com
- download.windowsupdate.com
- ntservicepack.microsoft.com
- windowsupdate.microsoft.com
- wustat.windows.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's urs.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

urs.microsoft.com
urs.smartscreen.microsoft.com